# Need a basename function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I need a short basename function (one-liner ?) for Javascript:

```
basename("/a/folder/file.a.ext") -> "file.a"
basename("/a/folder/file.ext") -> "file"
basename("/a/folder/file") -> "file"
```

That should strip the path and any extension.

Update:
For dot at the beginning would be nice to treat as "special" files

```
basename("/a/folder/.file.a.ext") -> ".file.a"
basename("/a/folder/.file.ext") -> ".file"
basename("/a/folder/.file") -> ".file" # empty is Ok
basename("/a/folder/.fil") -> ".fil"  # empty is Ok
basename("/a/folder/.file..a..") -> # does'nt matter
```

Comment: What should `basename('.foo')` be?

Comment: @bobince - Empty string I believe.

Comment: I’ve just arrived at `/^(?:.*\/(?=[^/]))?([^/]*)\/*$/.exec(pathname)[1]` for a more Unixy or useful basename: any trailing slashes are ignored, empty string if input is empty or solely comprised of slashes, otherwise right-most non-slash word. Reviews welcome (please @ me)!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
function baseName(str)
{
   var base = new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
    if(base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1)       
        base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
   return base;
}
```

If you can have both `/` and `\` as separators, you have to change the code to add one more line

Comment: @Sibidharan can you elaborate?

Comment: Why is the `new String(str)` needed and not just `str.substring(...)`?

Answer (score 120):

```
function basename(path) {
   return path.split('/').reverse()[0];
}
```

Breaks up the path into component directories and filename then returns the last piece (the filename) which is the last element of the array.

Comment: `path.split(/[\\/]/).pop();` - works with both separators, and no need to reverse

Comment: I think you should use `this` inside the function instead of variable name . so not select first class element only .

Comment: @3DFace There seems to be a couple of weird characters (`&zwnj;&#8203;`) between the `.` and `pop()` in your code.

Comment: @LarsNyström It's strange, couse there are ascii characters only. URL-encoded version for you:  
path.split(%2F%5B%5C%5C%2F%5D%2F).pop()%3B  
Hope, you can deocde :)

Comment: @3DFace That's strange, those characters are gone now. Must have been some cosmic radiation or something... Thanks for the code anyway, it works like a charm.

Comment: That awkward moment where the first comment has more votes than both the answer and the accepted answer 0_o +1 @3DFace

Comment: @3DFace that first comment could have earned you some serious reputation had you posted it in the form of an answer.

Comment: Does not work because it includes the file extension.

Answer (score 41):

Any of the above works although they have no respect for speed/memory :-).

A [faster](https://jsbench.me/iukvumzlob/1)/simpler implementation should uses as fewer functions/operations as possible. RegExp is a bad choice because it consumes a lot of resources when actually we can achieve the same result but easier.

An implementation when you want the filename including extension (which in fact this is *the genuine definition* of basename):

```
function basename(str, sep) {
    return str.substr(str.lastIndexOf(sep) + 1);
}
```

If you need a custom *basename implementation* that has to strip also the extension I would recommend instead a specific extension-stripping function for that case which you can call it whenever you like.

```
function strip_extension(str) {
    return str.substr(0,str.lastIndexOf('.'));
}
```

**Usage example:**

```
basename('file.txt','/'); // real basename
strip_extension(basename('file.txt','/')); // custom basename
```

They are separated such that you can combine them to obtain 3 different things: stripping the extention, getting the real-basename, getting your custom-basename. I regard it as a more elegant implementation than others approaches.

Comment: This is the most accurate and optimal answer. Thanks!

Comment: Speed is only important inside loops, especially innermost loops. Memory is only important when allocating many objects, especially large objects, at the same time. For a 'basename' function, which is not critical code, this answer is perfect.

Comment: If you have both scenarios with and without extension I altered strip_extension code: return str.substr(0, (str.lastIndexOf('.')==-1) ? str.length : str.lastIndexOf('.'));

Comment: `substr` is deprecated. Use `slice` in place.

Answer (score 22):

Maybe try to use existing packages if you can.  http://nodejs.org/api/path.html

```
var path = require('path');
var str = '/path/to/file/test.html'

var fileNameStringWithoutExtention = path.basename(str, '.html');
// returns 'test'

// let path determine the extension
var fileNameStringWithoutExtention = path.basename(str, path.extname(str));
// returns 'test'
```

Other examples:

```
var pathString = path.dirname(str);
var fileNameStringWithExtention = path.basename(str);
var fullPathAndFileNameString = path.join(pathString, fileNameString);
```

Comment: @Randy: Exactly what I needed! Under nodejs, no need to reinvent the wheel. (@Tazo, you are wrong about downloading. It's already there.)

Comment: @Randy I don't know why people uses custom function to get the filename instead of what you done

Answer (score 7):

```
 basename = function(path) {
    return path.replace(/.*\/|\.[^.]*$/g, '');
 }
```

replace anything that ends with a slash `.*\/` or dot - some non-dots - end `\.[^.]*$` with nothing

Answer (score 4):

Just like @3DFace has commented:

```
path.split(/[\\/]/).pop(); // works with both separators
```

Or if you like prototypes:

```
String.prototype.basename = function(sep) {
  sep = sep || '\\/';
  return this.split(new RegExp("["+sep+"]")).pop();
}
```

Testing:

```
var str = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820381/need-a-basename-function-in-javascript";
alert(str.basename());
```

Will return "need-a-basename-function-in-javascript".

Enjoy!

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to misinformation provided above, regular expressions are extremely efficient.  The caveat is that, when possible, they should be in a position so that they are compiled exactly once in the life of the program.

Here is a solution that gives both *dirname* and *basename*.

```
const rx1 = /(.*)\/+([^/]*)$/;    // (dir/) (optional_file)
const rx2 = /()(.*)$/;            // ()     (file)

function dir_and_file(path) {
  // result is array with
  //   [0]  original string
  //   [1]  dirname
  //   [2]  filename
  return rx1.exec(path) || rx2.exec(path);
}
// Single purpose versions.
function dirname(path) {
  return (rx1.exec(path) || rx2.exec(path))[1];
}
function basename(path) {
  return (rx1.exec(path) || rx2.exec(path))[2];
}
```

As for performance, I have not measured it, but I expect this solution to be in the same range as the fastest of the others on this page, but this solution does more.  Helping the real-world performance is the fact that `rx1` will match most actual paths, so `rx2` is rarely executed.

Here is some test code.

```
function show_dir(parts) {
  console.log("Original str :"+parts[0]);
  console.log("Directory nm :"+parts[1]);
  console.log("File nm      :"+parts[2]);
  console.log();
}
show_dir(dir_and_file('/absolute_dir/file.txt'));
show_dir(dir_and_file('relative_dir////file.txt'));
show_dir(dir_and_file('dir_no_file/'));
show_dir(dir_and_file('just_one_word'));
show_dir(dir_and_file('')); // empty string
show_dir(dir_and_file(null));
```

And here is what the test code yields:

```
# Original str :/absolute_dir/file.txt
# Directory nm :/absolute_dir
# File nm      :file.txt
# 
# Original str :relative_dir////file.txt
# Directory nm :relative_dir
# File nm      :file.txt
# 
# Original str :dir_no_file/
# Directory nm :dir_no_file
# File nm      :
# 
# Original str :just_one_word
# Directory nm :
# File nm      :just_one_word
# 
# Original str :
# Directory nm :
# File nm      :
# 
# Original str :null
# Directory nm :
# File nm      :null
```

By the way, "node" has a built in module called "path" that has "dirname" and "basename".  Node's "path.dirname()" function accurately imitates the behavior of the "bash" shell's "dirname," but is that good?  Here's what it does:

1. Produces `'.'` (dot) when `path==""` (empty string).
2. Produces `'.'` (dot) when `path=="just_one_word"`.
3. Produces `'.'` (dot) when `path=="dir_no_file/"`.

I prefer the results of the function defined above.

Answer (score 4):

Using modern (2020) js code:

```js
function basename (path) {
  return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
}
console.log(basename('/home/user/file.txt'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Another good solution:

```
function basename (path, suffix) {
  //  discuss at: http://locutus.io/php/basename/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kvz.io)
  // improved by: Ash Searle (http://hexmen.com/blog/)
  // improved by: Lincoln Ramsay
  // improved by: djmix
  // improved by: Dmitry Gorelenkov
  //   example 1: basename('/www/site/home.htm', '.htm')
  //   returns 1: 'home'
  //   example 2: basename('ecra.php?p=1')
  //   returns 2: 'ecra.php?p=1'
  //   example 3: basename('/some/path/')
  //   returns 3: 'path'
  //   example 4: basename('/some/path_ext.ext/','.ext')
  //   returns 4: 'path_ext'

  var b = path
  var lastChar = b.charAt(b.length - 1)

  if (lastChar === '/' || lastChar === '\\') {
    b = b.slice(0, -1)
  }

  b = b.replace(/^.*[\/\\]/g, '')

  if (typeof suffix === 'string' && b.substr(b.length - suffix.length) === suffix) {
    b = b.substr(0, b.length - suffix.length)
  }

  return b
}
```

from: http://locutus.io/php/filesystem/basename/

Answer (score 2):

### Defining a flexible `basename` implementation

Despite all the answers, I still had to produce my own solution which fits the following criteria:

1. Is fully portable and works in any environment (thus Node's `path.basename` won't do)
2. Works with both kinds of separators (`/` and `\`)
3. Allows for mixing separators - e.g. `a/b\c` (this is different from Node's implementation which respects the underlying system's separator instead)
4. Does not return an empty path if path ends on separator (i.e. `getBaseName('a/b/c/') === 'c'`)

### Code

(make sure to open the console before running the Snippet)

```js
/**
 * Flexible `basename` implementation
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/a/59907288/2228771
 */
function getBasename(path) {
  // make sure the basename is not empty, if string ends with separator
  let end = path.length-1;
  while (path[end] === '/' || path[end] === '\\') {
    --end;
  }

  // support mixing of Win + Unix path separators
  const i1 = path.lastIndexOf('/', end);
  const i2 = path.lastIndexOf('\\', end);

  let start;
  if (i1 === -1) {
    if (i2 === -1) {
      // no separator in the whole thing
      return path;
    }
    start = i2;
  }
  else if (i2 === -1) {
    start = i1;
  }
  else {
    start = Math.max(i1, i2);
  }
  return path.substring(start+1, end+1);
}

// tests
console.table([
  ['a/b/c', 'c'],
  ['a/b/c//', 'c'],
  ['a\\b\\c', 'c'],
  ['a\\b\\c\\', 'c'],
  ['a\\b\\c/', 'c'],
  ['a/b/c\\', 'c'],
  ['c', 'c']
].map(([input, expected]) => {
  const result = getBasename(input);
  return {
    input, 
    result,
    expected,
    good: result === expected ? '✅' : '❌'
  };
}));
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I needed to handle all browsers and platforms!!!

Answer (score 2):

Fast without regular expressions, suitable for both path types '/' and '\'. Gets the extension also:

```
function baseName(str)
{
    let li = Math.max(str.lastIndexOf('/'), str.lastIndexOf('\\'));
    return new String(str).substring(li + 1);
}
```

Comment: Instead of the Math.max function why not use ||.  This of course is susceptible to an invalid(?) string that contains / and \ characters.  But if the full path is valid, then this shouldn't happen.  Finally, it was asked before, but I didn't see that answer, why the new String vs just String?

Answer (score 1):

```
function basename(url){
    return ((url=/(([^\/\\\.#\? ]+)(\.\w+)*)([?#].+)?$/.exec(url))!= null)? url[2]: '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A nice one line, using ES6 arrow functions:

```js
var basename = name => /([^\/\\]*|\.[^\/\\]*)\..*$/gm.exec(name)[1];
// In response to @IAM_AL_X's comments, even shorter and it
// works with files that don't have extensions:
var basename = name => /([^\/\\\.]*)(\..*)?$/.exec(name)[1];
```

Comment: Three comments.  (1) The parenthesized expression has a pipe, ie. a '|', i.e. an "or", separating two sub-expressions, but the 2nd expression is indistinguishable from the 1st.  The 1st says "anything but slash or back-slash," the 2nd says "a dot followed by (the same);" but the "dot" part of the 2nd expression fulfills the "anything but" condition of the 1st, so they are effectively identical.  (2) You require that a "dot" must be present, i.e. you assume the filename include a dot suffix. (3) You provide the flags "gm"; it seems rare, if ever, that those flags provide something useful, here.

Comment: @IAM_AL_X, thank you for the most useful comment I have ever received on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

This is my implementation which I use in my fundamental js file.

```
// BASENAME

Window.basename = function() {
    var basename = window.location.pathname.split(/[\\/]/);
    return basename.pop() || basename.pop();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Functions for **basename** and also **dirname**:

```js
function basename(path) {
     return path.replace(/.*\//, '');
}

function dirname(path) {
     return path.match(/.*\//);
}
```

Sample:

```
Input                       dirname()           basename()
/folder/subfolder/file.ext  /folder/subfolder/  file.ext
/folder/subfolder           /folder/            subfolder
/file.ext                   file.ext            /
file.ext                    file.ext            null
```

See [reference](https://www.abeautifulsite.net/javascript-functions-for-basename-and-dirname).

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple using regex:

```
function basename(input) {
   return input.split(/\.[^.]+$/)[0];
}
```

Explanation:

Matches a single dot character, followed by any character except a dot (`[^.]`), one or more times (`+`), tied to the end of the string (`$`).

It then splits the string based on this matching criteria, and returns the first result (ie everything before the match).

[EDIT]
D'oh. Misread the question -- he wants to strip off the path as well. Oh well, this answers half the question anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_basename('http://www.example.com/dir/file.php?param1=blabla#cprod',   '/',  '?');
// returns:  file.php
```

CODE:

```
function my_basename(str, DirSeparator, FileSeparator) { var x= str.split(DirSeparator); return x[x.length-1].split(FileSeparator)[0];}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your original string or text file contains a single backslash character, you could locate it by using `'\\'`.

In my circumstance, I am using JavaScript to find the index of `"\N"` from a text file. And `str.indexOf('\\N');` helped me locate the `\N` from the original string, which is read from the source file.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

An improved version which works with forward `/` and backslash `\` single or double means either of the following

- `\\path\\to\\file`
- `\path\to\file`
- `//path//to//file`
- `/path/to/file`
- `http://url/path/file.ext`
- `http://url/path/file`

See a working demo below

```js
let urlHelper = {};
urlHelper.basename = (path) => {
  let isForwardSlash = path.match(/\/{1,2}/g) !== null;
  let isBackSlash = path.match(/\\{1,2}/g) !== null;

  if (isForwardSlash) {
    return path.split('/').reverse().filter(function(el) {
      return el !== '';
    })[0];
  } else if (isBackSlash) {
    return path.split('\\').reverse().filter(function(el) {
      return el !== '';
    })[0];
  }
  return path;
};

$('em').each(function() {
  var text = $(this).text();
  $(this).after(' --> <strong>' + urlHelper.basename(text) + '</strong><br>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<em>http://folder/subfolder/file.ext</em><br>
<em>http://folder/subfolder/subfolder2</em><br>
<em>/folder/subfolder</em><br>
<em>/file.ext</em><br>
<em>file.ext</em><br>
<em>/folder/subfolder/</em><br>
<em>//folder//subfolder//</em><br>
<em>//folder//subfolder</em><br>
<em>\\folder\\subfolder\\</em><br>
<em>\\folder\\subfolder\\file.ext</em><br>
<em>\folder\subfolder\</em><br>
<em>\\folder\\subfolder</em><br>
<em>\\folder\\subfolder\\file.ext</em><br>
<em>\folder\subfolder</em><br>
```

---

A more simpler solution could be

```
function basename(path) {
      return path.replace(/\/+$/, "").replace( /.*\//, "" );
}

Input                           basename()
/folder/subfolder/file.ext   --> file.ext
/folder/subfolder            --> subfolder
/file.ext                    --> file.ext
file.ext                     --> file.ext
/folder/subfolder/           --> subfolder
```

**Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Smartik/2c20q0ak/1/**

Comment: This function is not even valid. And it return nothing if the path ends with slash.... Ehh!

Comment: you are right about the trailing slash it returns nothing , and that is logical as the basename is mostly used for extracting filename from the url, let me check if i can update it to work for paths ending in /