# How do I copy a certain part of data from one form field to another in jquery/mootools

Tags: jquery, forms, mootools

I have 2 form input fields one is a image upload one is a text input I need to just take the image file name from the image upload field without the /images/and the .jpg

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

From this post: [Need a basename function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820381/need-a-basename-function-in-javascript/3820412#3820412)

```
function baseName(str) {
    var base = new String(str).substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1); 
    if(base.lastIndexOf(".") != -1) 
        base = base.substring(0, base.lastIndexOf("."));
    return base;
}
```

You can use it by inputting a string into the function like so:

```
var fileName = baseName("path/to/file/image.jpg");
```