# Using Regex to extract word

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a pattern as follows:

document_data/Filename.xyz

I'm trying to write a regular expression that will only return "Filename".  I have one that gives me just "xyz" and it works, and I have one that gives me "Filename.xyz" but I"m having trouble chopping off the xyz to just get Filename.

`[^/]+$` gives me `"Filename.xyz"`
`\[^.]+$` gives me `xyz`

I'm not a regex person so any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a basename function in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820381/need-a-basename-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

try to use a lookahead `(?=...)`:

```
/[^\/.]+(?=\.[^.]+$)/
```

A lookahead performs only a check and means *followed by* but match nothing.

Comment: one of my co-workers came up with this one and it seems to work. It all seems so simple now!

/[a-zA-Z0-9]+

Thanks to all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two and wrap the first part in a capturing group:

```
"document_data/Filename.xyz".match(/([^/]+)\.[^.]+$/)[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope its could help (cf: http://planetozh.com/blog/2008/04/javascript-basename-and-dirname/)

```
    function basename(path) {
        return path.replace(/\\/g,'/').replace( /.*\//, '' ).replace( /\..*/, '' );
    }
```