# Remove users file path from my file upload input

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Resolved:** The [fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5ovxdL/2/) thanks to @Abdallah Arffak

I would like to remove the ../../../ from a chosen file to upload and instead simply show the file name such as index.html or whatnot.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5u5ovxdL/

**HTML**

```
<div id="file">Chose file</div>
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

**JQuery**

```
var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'});
var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

fileInput.change(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $('#file').text($this.val());
})

$('#file').click(function(){
    fileInput.click();
}).show();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need a basename function in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820381/need-a-basename-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I want to trail back to the '/' does that other question not simply remove the up to the '.'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
fileInput.change(function(){
    $this = $(this);
    var file = $this.val().split("\\");
    if(file.length)
      $('#file').text(file[file.length-1]);
})
```

Comment: Just updated my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5u5ovxdL/1/) however it doesn't seem to do the job.

Comment: i update my code, you have to use this split("\\") instead of split("/");