# How to add semicolon before $('input[name="website"]').val(window.location.href).change();

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quick question! How can I add a semicolon before the value that is returned for

```
  onFormReady: function($form) {
    $('input[name="website"]').val(window.location.href).change();
  }
```

That returns that URL correctly, but I need a semicolon to appear before that value that is returned.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If your code returns the URL, then you can do `";" + <your code>`

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what happens. What isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
';' + $('input[name="website"]').val(window.location.href).change();
```

Comment: jQuery's [`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change) does not return a string. It sounds like OP wants something more like `.val(';' + window.location.href)`

Comment: @Phil Did you just assume I use jQuery?

Comment: I assumed OP was using jQuery given the `$`, `.val()` and `.change()`

Comment: @Phil, .val(';' + window.location.href) is exactly what I needed. That worked. Thank you.

Comment: @Phil If I change window.location.href to window.location.pathname, it gives me the path only, which is great, but how can I extract only the final part of the path (i.e. everything after the final /)?

Comment: @user3345500 [Need a basename function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3820381/need-a-basename-function-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks. Will have to spend some time figuring out how to use that with the code in my original post.  This is pretty foreign to me.  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Is there any way to merge everything into my original code, like...

window.location.pathname.split("/").pop()

...or some sort of merging of lastIndexOf within the code I already have?